# Quick Scroll Bar por ordem alfabética

Tags: android, rolamento

Eu já encontrei alguns exemplos com uma custom view de uma lista com uma *barra de rolagem rápida alfabética*, mas eu realmente não encontrei uma barra de rolagem que realmente se pareça com a da lista de contatos do meu kitkat.

Eu não entendo por que isso não é um elemento nativo, já que é usado em qualquer android desde a versão 4.0.

Eu tenho um exemplo usando SectionIndexer para ordenar e dividir por ordem alfabética - que fiz na época para ser como o do iOS - mas é velho e muito feio:

[image]

Eu quero um scrollbar como este:

[image]

Alguém tem algum exemplo ou dica para me passar?

=========================================================================

**UPDATE - RESOLVIDO**

Encontrei esse exemplo na página de Developers Android, e no sidebar direito você poder fazer o download do source de um exemplo perfeito!

Segue o [link](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html)

Comment: Considere a possibilidade de elaborar a solução no campo de respostas, para ajudar outros com o mesmo problema.

Comment: não sabia o que seria melhor, farei então

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei [esse exemplo na página de Developers Android](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html), e no sidebar direito você poder fazer o download do source de um exemplo perfeito!

> ## [Retrieving a List of Contacts](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html)
>
> This lesson shows you how to retrieve a list of contacts whose data matches all or part of a search string, using the following techniques:
>
> **Match contact names**
> Retrieve a list of contacts by matching the search string to all or part of the contact name data. The Contacts Provider allows multiple instances of the same name, so this technique can return a list of matches.
>
> **Match a specific type of data, such as a phone number**
> Retrieve a list of contacts by matching the search string to a particular type of detail data such as an email address. For example, this technique allows you to list all of the contacts whose email address matches the search string.
>
> **Match any type of data**
> Retrieve a list of contacts by matching the search string to any type of detail data, including name, phone number, street address, email address, and so forth. For example, this technique allows you to accept any type of data for a search string and then list the contacts for which the data matches the string.
>
> *Note: All the examples in this lesson use a [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/CursorLoader.html) to retrieve data from the Contacts Provider. A CursorLoader runs its query on a thread that's separate from the UI thread. This ensures that the query doesn't slow down UI response times and cause a poor user experience. For more information, see the Android training class [Loading Data in the Background](http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html).*

Answer (score 0):

XML dentro de um layout:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Activity você precisa de um List de Strings então caso você tenha uma lista complexa deve pegar o item que necessita conforme no exemplo:

```
public class Activity extends Activity {

ListView list_view;

private List<MeuItem> items;
private List<String> nomes;
private SimpleAdapter indexAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    setContentView(R.layout.myview);
    items = new ArrayList<MeuItem>();
    nomes = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Item i : items) {
        nomes.add(i.getNomeQueEuQueroQueApareca());
    }

    Collections.sort(nomes);
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, nomes);
    list_view.setAdapter(adapter);  

  }
}
```

Comment: Isso eh uma lista simples, eu quero uma com divisao alfabetica como a lista de contatos, mas eu já consegui um exemplo. Depois posto aqui

Comment: Uma pena você não ter testado o código que demorei alguns minutos para reescrever.
O que você quer é nativo e o que faz funcionar são as linhas:
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
Teste e não precisará de nenhuma library.

Comment: Na vdd eu conheço esses atributos, foram inclusive os que eu usei no primeiro exemplo, mas de longe isso resolve oq eu preciso. Tenho q utilizar sectionIndexer e AlphabetIndexer. Mas obrigado mesmo assim